# Telerik report in a popup won't open a second time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dom, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am displaying a Telerik report in a Telerik MVC popup window which is instantiated in client-side code.  Everything works fine the first time --  the report appears normally.

But if the window is closed (as it will be) and the user clicks for a second time the button on the page that opens the popup, the popup opens but no report content appears.  Here is the client code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#printButton').click(function () {
        var printPopup = $.telerik.window.create({
            title: "Resident Account Report",
            contentUrl: '/myApp/ReportPages/ReportPage.aspx' + '?rpt=myReport&ID=' + @Model.id,
            actions: ["Refresh", "Maximize", "Close"],
            height: 600,
            width: 1100,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            scrollable: false,
            onRefresh: function () {
                var myWindow = $(this).data('tWindow');
                myWindow.center().open();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is the problem because the first popup instance still exists in the DOM and needs to be disposed?

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the problem you explained above is exactly the cause. Closing MVC popup windows does not dispose the object loaded into MVC Popup Window. So either you dispose and reload the report module for each popup or just use the export the report content from the original page to your popup, this way your content will always be in parent window and popup will just be used to view exported report data.

Comment: How do I dispose of the report module in .net core?

The report viewer launches a new window, but sometimes it does not load the report. I am assuming it's because the viewer was not disposed of last time it was used?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is almost 1.5 years old, but I faced same issue and I have a solution for it, so sharing solution for my brothers who will face this issue in future.

In my case I was returning entire view from Action in response to ajaxRequest(). and in that case it was also returning all JS files, CSS files etc. which are conflicting with existing files.

When i changed my action to return partial view everything works like charm.

Thank you,
Sandesh Daddi

Comment: This is how I accomplished this task as well. +1